# Comparing and Merging 2 struct at run time

Tags: go, reflection

I'm trying to compare 2 struct at run time. I can't seem to compare the field one by one.
I'm thinking i would need to cast the type for each field while running my loop  but `reflect.TypeOf()` doesn't give me expected result of "type" ( int / string in that case ).
I'm thinking it's because i'm providing an interface{} as an argument? is there any way to make it work ?

My goal is to be able to compare value from 2 structs of the same type and " merge " the values into one struct if there's any differences.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type A struct {
    Foo string
    Bar int
    Zoo int
}

func main() {
    a := &A{Foo: "qwer",Bar:1}
    b := &A{Foo: "zxcv",Bar:1}
    testRefactor(a,b)

}

func testRefactor(t *A,comp *A) {
    valt := reflect.ValueOf(t).Elem()
    //valComp := reflect.ValueOf(comp).Elem()
    for i:=0; i<valt.NumField();i++{
        //fieldStructComp := valComp.Type().Field(i).Name
        fieldStructT := valt.Type().Field(i).Name


    valueStructComp := getFieldValueByname(comp,fieldStructT)
    valueStructT := getFieldValueByname(t,fieldStructT)

    typex := reflect.TypeOf(valueStructT)
    fmt.Println(typex.String())

        fmt.Println(valueStructT)
        fmt.Println(valueStructComp)
        fmt.Println(valueStructT == valueStructComp)

    }
}

func getFieldValueByname(structName interface{},fieldname string) interface{} {
    r := reflect.ValueOf(structName)
        f := reflect.Indirect(r).FieldByName(fieldname)
       return f
}
```

Comment: You can use `*t == *comp` to compare the struct type shown in the question.   Is merging the structs different from assigning one struct value to the other struct value?

Comment: Yes because one of the 2 struct can have empty fields  &A{Foo: "qwer",Bar:1,Zoo:2} + &A{Foo: "foo"} should return  &A{Foo: "foo",Bar:1,Zoo:2} struct field could also be a pointer *string and i could need to keep the nil value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that a simple struct like the one in the question can be compared with `==`.

```
func main() {
    a := &A{Foo: "qwer", Bar: 1}
    b := &A{Foo: "zxcv", Bar: 1}
    c := &A{Foo: "qwer", Bar: 1}
    d := &A{Foo: "zxcv", Bar: 1}

    fmt.Println(*a == *b)
    fmt.Println(*a == *c)
    fmt.Println(*b == *d)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/7W8qk6db4Uu

---

Note also that the order of fields is static, for comparing values of two structs of the same type you can do a basic loop and use `i` to access the corresponding fields (types and values) of both struct instances.

i.e. the `getFieldValueByname` function is unnecessary, you don't need it.

```
func testRefactor(a, b *A) {
    av := reflect.ValueOf(a).Elem()
    bv := reflect.ValueOf(b).Elem()
    at := av.Type()
    bt := bv.Type()

    for i := 0; i < av.NumField(); i++ {
        afv := av.Field(i)
        bfv := bv.Field(i)

        aft := at.Field(i)
        bft := bt.Field(i)

        fmt.Printf("a.%s <%s> = %v\n", aft.Name, aft.Type, afv)
        fmt.Printf("b.%s <%s> = %v\n", bft.Name, bft.Type, bfv)
        fmt.Printf("== ? %t\n", afv.Interface() == bfv.Interface())
        fmt.Println()

    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/G1EhMeYYqud

---

For merging values of two different structs you can start with this:

```
func testRefactor(a, b interface{}) {
    av := reflect.ValueOf(a).Elem()
    bv := reflect.ValueOf(b).Elem()
    at := av.Type()
    bt := bv.Type()

    for i := 0; i < av.NumField(); i++ {
        afv := av.Field(i)
        aft := at.Field(i)

        bfv := bv.FieldByName(aft.Name)
        bft, ok := bt.FieldByName(aft.Name)
        if !ok || aft.Type != bft.Type {
            continue
        }

        fmt.Printf("a.%s <%s> = %v\n", aft.Name, aft.Type, afv)
        fmt.Printf("b.%s <%s> = %v\n", bft.Name, bft.Type, bfv)
        fmt.Printf("== ? %t\n", afv.Interface() == bfv.Interface())
        fmt.Println()

        if afv.Interface() != bfv.Interface() {
            afv.Set(bfv)
        }

    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/9alFY4oBNZh

Comment: The goal is to make it work with any kind of struct so that i can use it to update one struct with the fields from another i'm not trying to compare them altogether as the result is useless to me. I'm trying to make it so that if Struct1.FooField != Struct2.FooField then Struct1.FooField = Struct2FooField , where struct1 is the original struct data and struct 2 the "updated " data. 
And since there's many different kind of struct for which i'll need to do this i need it work with any kind of struct

Comment: also in your 2nd example if you add : `fmt.Println(afv == bfv)` it'll always return false that's why i was trying to cast the type as i thought that was the issue.

Comment: @user7952151 I've updated the answer. Note that while `afv` and `bfv` are structs they are not simple ones like you have in your question, plus they also hold information about their "context" which can, and in this case *is*, different even though the underlying value may be the same. So to compare the field's actual values you have to use the `Interface()` method to get the underlying value of the `reflect.Value` instance.

Comment: tyvm for helpinrg